# Determine if some application is currently using microphone

Tags: audio, microphone

Is it possible to determine if some application is currently using microphone (i.e. is actively listening)?

Do operating systems (Windows in my case, but I'm curious about other OS-es as well) provide APIs for such feature?

I'm trying to test if apps are spying on users and data from such feature could serve as circumstantial evidence.

Comment: Android: [How can I detect which background application is using the camera, microphone or GPRS?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/40284)

Comment: Mac: [Micro Snitch](https://obdev.at/products/microsnitch/index.html)